# Component not showing up in react router with laravel

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to React and I am trying to display a react route using react router dom but the matching component is not coming up. I have looked at answers from other OS questions related but no help. Here is my app.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import AdminLogin from './AdminLogin';


export default class AdminApp
 extends Component {
   render() {
     return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <div className="App">
                        <Route path="/" exact={true}  component = {AdminLogin} />
                </div>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}
}

if (document.getElementById('app')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<AdminApp />, document.getElementById('app'));
}
```

When i inspect my html file i get this

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="App" location="[object Object]" computedmatch="[object Object]"></div>
</div>
```

this is my adminLogin component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {adminLogin} from './UserFunctions';

export default class AdminLogin extends Component {
    constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        errors: {}
    }
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
}

onChange(e){
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
}

onSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    const user = {
        email : this.state.email,
        password : this.state.password
    }

    adminLogin(user).then(res => {
        if(res) {
            this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
        }
    })
}


render(){
    return (
        <div className="kt-grid kt-grid--ver kt-grid--root">
            <div className="kt-grid kt-grid--hor kt-grid--root  kt-login>
                  <h1>Login Now</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

}
```

Comment: Can you share your `AdminLogin` component?

Comment: Seems like your routing is correct. Please see this sample I put together with your code. https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-river-jypnl

Comment: @UdithGunaratna i ran your code and it did not work.

Comment: There is an error in your `AdminLogin` component. You haven't closed the className string of inner div element. It should be `<div className="kt-grid kt-grid--hor kt-grid--root  kt-login">`

Comment: I edited my code and removed all the tags and just returned hello in my adminLogin and nothing outputs still

Comment: Also instead of `<Router><Switch><div className="App"><Route>`, use `<Router><div className="App"><Switch><Route>`

Comment: @UdithGunaratna still not working

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @UdithGunaratna no errors. I changed all that is inside the switch tag including the switch tag and replaced it with <AdminLogin /> and it rendered what i have in the AdminLogin component just fine

Comment: Do you only have this route in your router? Or are there any other routes defined as well?

Comment: i have just this route. Yet to define any other route.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200126/discussion-between-udith-gunaratna-and-patrick-obafemi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only works if you are trying the root path (`/`). If you need to render this component at a subpath (e.g. `/foo/bar/login`), that should be defined as the route path.

`<Route path="/foo/bar/login" exact={true}  component = {AdminLogin} />`